# Firewalld with an IP alias (eth0:0)

Tags: centos7, firewalld

***(Solution found, see below...)***

The server (CentOS 7) has multiple public IPs, these are set up via the usual `ifcfg-eth0:0` config files and are working fine. I'm trying to adapt to firewalld (coming from iptables). I like to be able to specify open ports per IP alias - with iptables this was done simply by setting the destination IP to match whatever alias needed the port.

I *thought* with firewalld I could apply a different zone to each interface to achieve the same effect, however it seems I cannot do so.

We start with:

```
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: eth0 eth0:0
trusted
  interfaces: eth1
```

I created a new zone `public_web` that I wanted to use for `eth0:0`

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=public_web
success
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public_web --add-service=http
success
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public_web --add-interface=eth0:0
success
# firewall-cmd --reload
success
```

But...

```
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: eth0 eth0:0
trusted
  interfaces: eth1
```

I tried `--remove-interface`, `--change-interface` and various other commands in various orders, but `eth0:0` won't budge. I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere about using aliases, so I'm not sure if this is even the correct way of achieving what I'd like?

Thanks all.

---

### Solution:

The solution is to use the `destination` tag in a service file, it can only be used once per service.

So let's say you want port 443 on 87.98.256.512, make a copy of the `https.xml` file (recommend you don't touch originals) to `/etc/firewalld/services`, here I'll use `https-admin.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>HTTPS for 87.98.256.512</short>
  <description>...</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="443"/>
  <destination ipv4="87.98.256.512" />
</service>
```

Then

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https-admin
success
# firewall-cmd --reload
success
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-services
http https-admin
```

And finally confirm this with iptables

```
Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            87.98.256.512        tcp dpt:443 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW
```

*Remember: only one `destination` tag per service, so just make multiple services if that's your requirement.*

Comment: You might want to include your solution as a separate answer, and accept it. Putting your answer in your question when there's this whole answer part to the Q&A is a bit weird.

Comment: The `eth0:0` interface alias has been deprecated for years and you should _not_ be using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire interface aliasing functionality is left over from the past.  It doesn't actually create a separate interface.  You haven't needed to use aliases to assign multiple IPs to a single interface for a long time.  Because it isn't a 'real' interface, your firewall software cannot treat it like a real interface.  If you use the `ip addr` command you will see that the addresses are all assigned to the main interface, and the `eth0:0` is simply considered to be a label for that address.

With all that in mind, I am not entirely sure what you need to do to adjust your firewall.  I suspect you may need to specify ports by IP, and not by the IP address and not the alias.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it helped with understanding the process. I found that you can specify a `destination` per service which works for my set-up.